# Biding contextmenu menuitem visibility with a list

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, listbox, contextmenu

I have a ContextMenu attached to a ListBox who offer two options : create and delete element. I want to hide only the "Delete" element if the ListBox data is empty.

I've tried to bind the property "Visibility" with a variable in the view's code setting it to "Collapsed" or "Visible", but it didn't work.

XAML :

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding ElementList}"
         SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedElement}"
         SelectionChanged="ListBoxProjects_SelectionChanged">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    <ListBox.ContextMenu>
        <ContextMenu>
            <MenuItem Name="Add" Click="Add_Click" Header="Add element" />
            <MenuItem Name="Delete" Click="Delete_Click" 
                      HeaderStringFormat="Delete element {0}" 
                      Header="{Binding SelectedElement.Name}" 
                      Visibility="{Binding ElementContextMenuVisibility}" />
        </ContextMenu>
    </ListBox.ContextMenu>
</ListBox>
```

CS :

```
public partial class View : UserControl
{
    private ViewModel _viewModel = ViewModel.Instance;

    private Visibility _elementContextMenuVisibility { get; set; }
    public Visibility ElementContextMenuVisibility
    {
        get { return _elementContextMenuVisibility; }
        set { _elementContextMenuVisibility = value; }
    }

    public View()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void ListBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (_viewModel.ElementList != null && _viewModel.ElementList.Count > 0)
            ElementContextMenuVisibility = Visibility.Visible;
        else
            ElementContextMenuVisibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
    }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Please add to your question the data binding errors you see in the Visual Studio's Output window.

Comment: why can't you do something like Visibility="{Binding ElementContextMenuVisibility, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVis}}"  in App.xaml  <BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="BoolToVis"/> and bind Visibility with some boolean property

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this with `RelativeSource` binding and no need of `xaml.cs` code.

**XAML**

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding ElementList}"
         SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedElement}">
    <ListBox.Resources>
        <BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="BooleanToVisibilityConverter"/>
    </ListBox.Resources>
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    <ListBox.ContextMenu>
        <ContextMenu>
            <MenuItem Name="Add" Click="Add_Click" Header="Add element" />
            <MenuItem Name="Delete" Click="Delete_Click" 
                      HeaderStringFormat="Delete element {0}" 
                      Header="{Binding SelectedElement.Name}" 
                      Visibility="{Binding PlacementTarget.HasItems, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ContextMenu}, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}" />
        </ContextMenu>
    </ListBox.ContextMenu>
</ListBox>
```

Comment: Fantastic ! It is exactly what I searched. Thank you.